# Writing to azure cosmos db from azure functions does not create any entities

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I am attempting to write to a cosmosDB service from an Azure functions script.
The function executes correctly and in my cosmosDB metrics I can see the requests coming in. The new tables and collections are also being created in cosmosDB, so the request is coming through.

No new entities are being created in the collection however. Am i forgetting something or understanding something wrongly?

**index.js**

```
module.exports = function (context, message) {
    context.bindings.testDocument = JSON.stringify({ 
        name: "name",
        duedate: "duedate",
        task: "task"
    });
    context.log('context binding set');
    context.done();
};
```

**function.json**

```
{
 "bindings": [
{
  "type": "eventHubTrigger",
  "name": "message",
  "direction": "in",
  "path": "samples-workitems",
  "connection": "MAP-hub_events_IOTHUB",
  "cardinality": "one",
  "consumerGroup": "$Default"
},
{
  "type": "documentDB",
  "name": "testDocument",
  "databaseName": "testDataBase",
  "collectionName": "testCollection",
  "createIfNotExists": true,
  "connection": "raw-data-storage_DOCUMENTDB",
  "direction": "out"
}
],
"disabled": false
}
```

**database**

screenshot of the created database and collection:

[image]

**metrics**

screenshot of the cosmosDB metrics:

[image]

Comment: What host version are you using (FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION under Application Settings)?

Comment: You might need to add leases collection?

Comment: Similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49928894/azure-function-cosmosdb-trigger-returned-encoded-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a Cosmos DB account with the **Table model**. The Table model has some schema restrictions in the documents you can send to it using the SQL API (the [Cosmos DB Output binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb#output) uses the SQL SDK to persist documents).

If you want to use the Output binding, try with a Cosmos DB SQL type of account.